# angularjs $stateProvider state abstract and spring boot

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot

I'm starting to study spring boot and angularjs, I found the routing methods very interesting, but I noticed one that would be ideal for my situation, but I can not succeed.

I would like some help or explanation about what is wrong on this point.

When I start my routing configuration, I make an abstract state to call a layout that contains a data-ui-view and it will display the rest of my application. This layout has menus, header, footer ...

But for some reason it does not call my layout.html and the screen goes blank.

Routing:

```
app
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
        function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
            $rootScope.$state = $state;
            $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            });
            FastClick.attach(document.body);
        },
    ])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

            // Remove da Url o " ! ", localhost:8080/#!/
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

            // Application routes
            $stateProvider
                .state('app', {
                    abstract: true,
                    templateUrl: 'views/common/layout.html',
                })


                .state('app.dashboard', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
                    resolve: {
                        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                                {
                                    insertBefore: '#load_styles_before',
                                    files: [
                                        'styles/climacons-font.css',
                                        'vendor/rickshaw/rickshaw.min.css'
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    serie: true,
                                    files: [
                                        'vendor/d3/d3.min.js',
                                        'vendor/rickshaw/rickshaw.min.js',
                                        'vendor/flot/jquery.flot.js',
                                        'vendor/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js',
                                        'vendor/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js',
                                        'vendor/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js',
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'angular-flot',
                                    files: [
                                        'vendor/angular-flot/angular-flot.js'
                                    ]
                                }]).then(function () {
                                return $ocLazyLoad.load('js/controllers/dashboard.js');
                            });
                        }]
                    },
                    data: {
                        title: 'Dashboard',
                    }
                })

}]);
```

Layout.html:

```
<!-- preloader -->
<preloader class="preloader ng-hide"></preloader>
<!-- /preloader -->

<!-- sidebar panel -->
<div class="sidebar-panel offscreen-left" data-ng-include="'./views/common/sidebar-panel.html'"></div>
<!-- /sidebar panel -->

<!-- content panel -->
<div class="main-panel">

  <!-- top header -->
  <div class="header navbar" data-ng-include="'./views/common/header.html'"></div>
  <!-- /top header -->

  <!-- main area -->
  <div class="main-content {{$state.current.data.contentClasses}}" data-ui-view="data-ui-view"></div>
  <!-- /main area -->

</div>
<!-- /content panel -->

<!-- bottom footer -->
<footer class="content-footer" data-ng-include="'./views/common/footer.html'"></footer>
<!-- /bottom footer -->

<!-- chat -->
<div class="chat-panel" data-ng-class="{'conversation-open': app.layout.isConversationOpen}" data-ng-include="'./views/common/chat-panel.html'"></div>
<!-- /chat -->

<!-- options panel -->
<div class="configuration" data-ng-include="'./views/common/options.html'" data-ng-class="{'active': app.isConfigOpen}"></div>
<!-- /options panel -->
```

Index.html:

```
<body data-ng-controller="appController" class="{{ app.layout.sidebarTheme }} {{ app.layout.headerTheme }}">

<!--<div data-ng-include="'./views/common/layout.html'"></div>-->





</body>

<div class="app {{$state.current.data.appClasses}}"
     data-ng-class="{'layout-small-menu': app.layout.isSmallSidebar,
                     'layout-chat-open': app.layout.isChatOpen,
                     'layout-fixed-header': app.layout.isFixedHeader,
                     'layout-boxed': app.layout.isBoxed,
                     'layout-static-sidebar': app.layout.isStaticSidebar,
                     'layout-right-sidebar': app.layout.isRightSidebar,
                     'layout-fixed-footer': app.layout.isFixedFooter,
                     'message-open': app.isMessageOpen}"
     data-ui-view="data-ui-view">
</div>
```

If you look at my index.hml, there is a commented line, this line is a forced call to my layout.html, in case I uncomment it, my layout.html is called twice, one receiving the other if I comment the line The screen returns empty again.
Thank you

Comment: I don't see that this has anything at all to do with the server-side pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hitting me hard I found what the problem was. Reading an article about angular, I was instructed that the ui-data-ui-view attribute should always be filled:

```
<div data-ui-view="data-ui-view">
```

Where I did this in my index.

The solution was the removal of the attribute value:

```
<div data-ui-view="">
```

Thank you